# One-to-many association won't save new form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently trying to display an organization'(s) which a deal identifies with via a collection_select form.

The issue which I have is after attempting to create a new deal and choosing an organization to assign it to. I receive an error message via a **pluralize error**.

The issue which pops up states:

**1 error prohibited this deal from being saved:**

- Organization must exist

I have tried searching the web for an answer so far but nothing has helped. I have also tried everything that I can think of is the issue with my code.

Here are my **models**:

```
class Deal < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :organization
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :organization
end

class Organization < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :contact_orgs
 has_many :contacts, through: :contact_orgs

 has_many :deals
end
```

Here is my **schema.rb**:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171217051027) do

create_table "contact_orgs", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer "organization_id"
 t.integer "contact_id"
 t.index ["contact_id"], name: "index_contact_orgs_on_contact_id"
 t.index ["organization_id"], name: 
 "index_contact_orgs_on_organization_id"
end

create_table "deals", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "name"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.integer "organization_id"
 t.index ["organization_id"], name: "index_deals_on_organization_id"
end

create_table "organizations", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string "name"
 t.datetime "created_at", null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 t.string "industry"
end

end
```

Here is my **deals_controller.rb**:

```
    def show
  @deal = Deal.find(params[:id])
end

def new
  @deal = Deal.new
end

def create
  @deal = Deal.new(deal_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @deal.save
      format.html { redirect_to @deal, notice: 'Deal was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @deal }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @deal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

private
 def deal_params
  params.require(:deal).permit(:name, organization_attributes: [:id])
 end
end
```

Here is my **deals/new.html.erb** file:

```
<%= form_with model: @deal, local: true do |form| %>

<% if @deal.errors.any? %>
 <div id="error_explanation">
  <h2>
    <%= pluralize(@deal.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited
    this deal from being saved:
  </h2>
  <ul>
    <% @deal.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
 </div>
<% end %>


<p>
 <%= form.label :name %><br>
 <%= form.text_field :name %>
</p>


<p>
 <%= form.label :organization %><br>
 <%= form.collection_select :organization, Organization.order(:name), :id, :name, {} %>
<p>

<p>
 <%= form.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

Thank you ahead of time :)

**Edit**:

```
Started GET "/deals/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-16 23:09:16 -0800
Processing by DealsController#new as HTML
Rendering deals/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Organization Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "organizations".* FROM 
"organizations" ORDER BY "organizations"."name" ASC
Rendered deals/new.html.erb within layouts/application (40.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 183ms (Views: 108.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.6ms)


Started POST "/deals" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-12-16 23:09:20 -0800
Processing by DealsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bmm6VsgpA6mmU4J+3J1EWSsgEyrNmhU1LAU5HhPe9cIApFyH6p6FLfEMDIksvyNVRz8vqjXexzFu/LsalFMpTQ==", "deal"=>{"name"=>"Test Deal - 1", "organization"=>"9"}, "commit"=>"Create Deal"}
Unpermitted parameter: :organization
(0.4ms)  begin transaction
(0.1ms)  rollback transaction
Rendering deals/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Organization Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "organizations".* FROM "organizations" ORDER BY "organizations"."name" ASC
Rendered deals/new.html.erb within layouts/application (10.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 77ms (Views: 56.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.2ms)
```

Comment: I guess you don't have to use `accepts_nested_attributes` for Deal model. Your form's select pass to server just `organization_id` field. Try remove `accepts_nested_attributes` and permit `organization_id` attribute.

Comment: You can use `accepts_nested_attributes` when you want to create/save several objects at the same time. But in your case the organizations exist already.

Comment: Okay, I tried removing `accepts_nested_attributes` and then permitting `organization_id` but I'm still receiving the same error message.

Comment: Can you show request's log of controller?

Comment: Or you can try to change your form with: `<%= form.collection_select :organization_id, ...` to exactly set the name of attribute

Comment: Alright, I added what I think you requested. I tried changing my form to exactly set the name of the attribute like you said and still getting the error.

Comment: Look, attributes you permit should equal attributes passed from form. Are you sure you permit `organization_id` and pass from form `organization_id`? As I can see from your log the situation is the following: form passes `"deal"=>{"name"=>"Test Deal - 1", "organization"=>"9"}`. If you permit `organization_id` it should be `"deal"=>{"name"=>"Test Deal - 1", "organization_id"=>"9"}`. Try `params.require(:deal).permit(:name, :organization_id)` with `<%= form.collection_select :organization_id, ...`

Comment: yes as user user3309314 suggested allow organization_id in permit present in your controller

Answer (score 1):

Parent should be created before create the child.